# What's the optimal way to calculate which integer in a list is missing?

Tags: algorithm

I was recently in an interview where they asked me technical questions. One was how you would calculate which number in a list of length n-1 was missing. The list contained every number from 1 to n, except i where 1 <= i <= n. The numbers were not in order. My solution was to add them all up, then subtract that from the calculation of the numbers from 1 to n, by adding 1 to n and multiplying by n/2 or (n-1)/2 as appropriate. But I got the sense that there was a better way to do it. What is the optimal solution?

Comment: Consider what the range would look like if you sorted it. If you can think of a word that starts with "P" you're on the right track.

Comment: But wouldn't sorting it require more work than my method? (And I'm sorry, I can't think of the word)

Comment: I'm not saying that sorting is the answer, just that you should think about what it would look like. Second letter is "e".

Comment: Permutation? I don't see what that has to do with it. (Not saying it doesn't, I'm just not sure what you mean).

Comment: I think your solution is optimal in time and space, as you are doing one pass over the list (and it looks like you need to see every item in the list at least once anyway), and using only 1 accumulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is good enough, in my opinion.

But some people -- perhaps your interviewer is one of them -- are worried about overflow and such.  In that case, use XOR instead of addition.

To obtain the XOR of the integers from 0 to n, just XOR together the array indices as you loop.  Given the XOR of the integers from 0 to n, and the XOR of the array elements, you just XOR the two of those together to get the missing element.

P.S.  The sum of the integers from 1 to n is always (n+1)*n/2

Comment: I like your XOR trick! It is interesting, however, that you do not need to worry about overflow to get the problem solved, as long as you know that your system keeps correct lower bits of the result. subtract the calculated (overflown) sum of numbers from the (also overflown) sum calculated using the Gaussian method, and, surprisingly, you'll get the number! The trick won't work if the system always checks for integer overflow (e.g., Ada). It won't also works on floats, but neither does the XOR trick. XOR trick requires a pass over the array, unless there is a closed formula like one for sum.

Comment: @kkm: The Gaussian method only avoids the overflow problem if you compute (n/2) or (n+1)/2 first (whichever is an integer).  If you multiply n by n+1, you lose the high bit and cannot get it back when you divide by 2.  But yes, other than that, doing the sum modulo 2^k works fine.

Answer (score 0):

while iterating through the array to calculate the sum, you can check whether if a number is repeating.

Comment: Could you expand on that, I can't see what you mean.

Comment: in your answer you had mentioned that solution can be calculated through calculating the sum and then subtracting it from the total. to calculate the sum you have to iterate thought the array.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean repeating? The numbers don't repeat.

Comment: what i was thinking is that, if one number is missing , value of that number will be replaced by existing number.i guess i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your method is absolutely fine. It is optimal in terms of both space and time. Overflow can be the only problem with it.

Another possible method could be using a hashSet. Create an initial hashSet having values 1->N. Now for each number you encounter in the list - delete that value from the hashSet. At the end, the value that remains in the hashSet is the missing value.

This method is O(N) in time and space complexity. Your method (barring overflow) was O(N) in time and O(1) complexity. The added 'n' factor for space is the cost for eliminating overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty much optimal with one change, as @Nemo points out the sum of integers from 1 to n is always `(n+1) * n/2`

It's also worth pointing out that your approach is multi-thread capable (and might suitable for very large values of N), split the array in to parts, then get the sum of each array part in a thread, then add those part sums. It depends what the overhead of threading is compared to adding numbers in an array.

If you're worried about overflows, and your values are always int32 (as most `.Length` values are including arrays) then just store the sum as a int64, the sum of all positive integer values `(((long)int.MaxValue) +1L) * (int.MaxValue / 2) = 2305843007066210304` which is still able to fit within a int64 with a `.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807`.

The other answer as mentioned by others is to XOR each item and keep a running XOR, but then you need to work out a formula to get the expected total XOR in `O(1)` time.

Most likely the interviewer is looking to see if you realise there's an `O(N)` solution with `O(1)` memory (which your answer is), rather than sorting the array and being much slower for very large values of `N`.

To further improve your solution in code, would be to use a pointer to access the array rather than the index value (which if your code is C# will be a reasonable improvement).